# Redirect inside Excel:load()

Tags: laravel

Hi I have an issue with the Excel::load() with Laravel. The situation is that if I want to do this... it does not redirect let me show you an example:

```
$excel = \Excel::load($request->excel, function($reader) 
{
  $excel = $reader->get();

  $reader->each(function($row, $error) 
  {
       // This does not redirect
       return Redirect::to('excel/create');

      //either this one
      return redirect('inventoryadmin/dashboard')->with('message', 'Comic Records Successfully Imported');
  });
});
```

Why do they not redirect? none of two work... so I wonder how can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: A `redirect()` doesn't do anything unless returned by the Controller. Try `return Excel::load()...` instead of `$excel = Excel()`, or `return $excel;`. That being said, this code doesn't make a whole lot of sense... Why are you redirecting inside your `Excel::load()` method to begin with?

Comment: I want to redirect inside my excel load because I want to validate if the excel sheet is well built because if there are some empty fields it will display an error and I want to avoid that. So I put the redirect to display an error sating that the excel sheet is not well built

Answer (score 0):

The context you're returning redirect from isn't a controller, it's inside your lambda function `function($reader){ ... }`

Returning redirect will only do something if you're returning it inside a controller. It's your controller that communicates with the client and tells it to redirect.